# Ignoring MSER components with bounding ellipse overlapping with a binary mask

Tags: matlab

This question seems a little basic, but I would like to have some inputs about an efficient way of doing this.
Suppose I have the following image :
[image]

I also have a binary mask image as follows :

[image]

I detect MSER features on this image and plot the corresponding bounding ellipses.
[image]

What I need is that I want all those MSER regions removed, whose bounded ellipses overlap with the mask image. My issue is that I have a number of such operations and have to process a large number of images. Thus, what is the most efficient and fast way of doing this, which requirest minimal memory usage ?

Comment: OT: that's a beautiful image, what does it represent?

Comment: I used it as an example image. I actually work in medical imaging and need the answer to do my work with those images :)

Comment: No worries, same position here : )

Answer (score 0):

It depends how your ellipses are stored, and perhaps on the size of your image. If they are represented as masks then I would be tempted to superimpose all the ellipses first and then do an intersection operation with the rectangle. Then you have a mask which you can apply to the original image.

If your ellipses are stored in a symbolic form - like the output of `regionprops` - it might be more efficient to test them against the rectangle first and only if they intersect would you convert it into a mask and add it to the overall mask.

Comment: My MSER regions are stored as a MSERObject. I basically use the detectMSERFeatures function of MATLAB. It returns a MSERObject, which contains the ellipse centroid, axes and orientation.

Comment: So the cost is going to be computing the extent of the ellipsoid. Perhaps you could do a first order comparison of the bounding box of the ellipsoid against the rectangle - this would be linear and pretty fast and would allow you to reject out of hand all the ellipses which are nowher near the mask rectangle. For the ones where the bounding box intersects then you could compute the ellipse mask and do a proper test.